# Irreducible polynomial $p_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for all positive integers $n$

Tags: polynomials

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $1$, and define the polynomial $$p_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$$

> Is $p_{n}(x)$  irreducible in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$?

I can show it when $n$ is a prime number, since
$$n!p_{n}(x)=x^n+nx^{n-1}+n(n-1)x^{n-2}+\cdots+n!x+n!$$ using Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Summation starts from $k=0$, right?

Comment: There is a fairly elementary proof at https://mattbakerblog.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/newton-polygons-and-galois-groups/ together with some more notes on the topic.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft,your link can't open it,Thanks,can you post this paper  title?

Comment: It works fine for me. It is a blog post, not a paper (though he has some references to papers in it).

Comment: Thanks,can you post his blog with title,maybe I can google it

Comment: It is called Matt Baker's Math Blog and the post is called Newton polygons and Galois groups

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft,Thanks,I have found it, because these days I try find more elementary proof

Comment: [This post on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130823/is-1x-fracx22-dots-fracxnn-irreducible) contains this link in the comments: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That follows from a theorem of Schur saying that any polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^nc_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$ with $c_i\in\mathbf{Z}$, $c_0,c_n\in\{1,-1\}$, $n\ge 1$, is irreducible over $\mathbf{Q}$.

I. Schur, Einige Sätze über Primzahlen mit Anwendungen auf Irreduzibilitätsfragen I, Sitzungsberichte
Preuss. Akad. Wiss. Phys.-Math. Klasse 14 (1929), 125–136. Also in Gesammelte Abhandlungen, Band
III, 140–151

See also [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf).

Comment: Thanks,maybe there exist  elementary proof? because  it's nice result,like the erdos methods?